# WebScraping, Ignore Missing Items in For Loop. Selenium and BS4, Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, beautifulsoup, error-handling

I am having trouble with the for loop in the code below. I am currently trying to **scrape ZocDoc** and am looking to **scrape multiple doctors url on the site for general info** like: name, rating, number of reviews, bedside manner rating, etc. But the **2 variables causing trouble are 'language_spanish' and 'language_english'.** For example, **if the doctor does not speak Spanish and it is not listed on their profile, the 'language_spanish' variable will return a ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'' error** since it does not exist in the HTML. If I **eliminate the 'language_spanish'** variable, the **'language_english' variable will work as well as the others**(assuming both doctors at least speak English)(The temporary url list below contains 1 doctor who speaks English and Spanish, the other a doctor who speaks English and Arabic). **How can I return a 'NULL' value for any one of the items in the for loop, should the item be missing on the doctors url.** Thank you for any help.

```
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

questionlist_zoc_temp = ('https://www.zocdoc.com/doctor/danilo-hoyumpa-md-241162?LocIdent=101038&reason_visit=75&insuranceCarrier=-1&insurancePlan=-1&dr_specialty=153&spoAdDecisionId=244725316&ad_decision_token=e97292ba-57d2-418a-9fdd-bc69645de83f','https://www.zocdoc.com/doctor/george-girgis-md-97120?LocIdent=56500&reason_visit=75&insuranceCarrier=-1&insurancePlan=-1&dr_specialty=153&isNewPatient=true')

dr_data = []

for urls_dr in questionlist_zoc_temp:
    
    
    driver.get(urls_dr)
    sleep(randint(4,10))

    soup_dr = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    

    
    for dr_item in soup_dr:
            dr_scraper = {
            'name': dr_item.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}).text,
            'specialties': dr_item.find('li', {'class':'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'}).text,    
            'review_count': dr_item.find('div', {'class':'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'}).text,
            'language_english': dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-English'}).text,
            #'language_spanish': dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}).text,    
            'overall_rating': dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-0'}).text,    
            'wait_time_rating': dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-1'}).text,   
            'bedside_manner_rating': dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-2'}).text
            }
            dr_data.append(dr_scraper)
```

**Ouput** (assuming the elimination of the 'language_spanish' item)

```
[{'name': 'Dr. Danilo Hoyumpa, MD', 'specialties': 'Family Physician', 'review_count': '1464 reviews', 'language_english': 'English', 'overall_rating': 'Overall rating4.87', 'wait_time_rating': 'Wait time4.91', 'bedside_manner_rating': 'Bedside manner4.91'}, {'name': 'Dr. George Girgis, MD', 'specialties': 'Family Physician', 'review_count': '174 reviews', 'language_english': 'English', 'overall_rating': 'Overall rating4.91', 'wait_time_rating': 'Wait time4.39', 'bedside_manner_rating': 'Bedside manner4.96'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a try except and set the value to NULL. Then pass the value to your data etc
'language_spanish': lang-span

```
try:
    lang-span=dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}).text
except:
    lang-span="NULL"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different ways you can go about this.  First the code-heavy way:

```
for dr_item in soup_dr:
    dr_scraper = {
        'name': None,
        'specialties': None,
        'review_count': None,
        'language_english': None,
        'language_spanish': None,
        'overall_rating': None,
        'wait_time_rating': None,
        'bedside_manner_rating: None
    }
    if dr_item.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}):
        dr_scraper['name] = dr_item.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}).text
    if dr_item.find('li', {'class':'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'}):
        dr_scraper['specialties'] = dr_item.find('li', {'class':'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'}).text
    if dr_item.find('div', {'class':'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'}):
        dr_scraper['review_count'] = dr_item.find('div', {'class':'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'}).text
    if dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-English'}):
        dr_scraper['language_english'] = dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-English'}).text
    if dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}):
        dr_scraper['language_spanish'] = dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}).text
    if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-0'}):
        dr_scraper['overall_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-0'}).text
    if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-1'}):
        dr_scraper['wait_time_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-1'}).text
    if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-2'}):
        dr_scraper['bedside_manner_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-2'}).text

    dr_data.append(dr_scraper)
```

That code could be condensed a bit:

```
for dr_item in soup_dr:
    dr_scraper = {}
    dr_scraper['name] = dr_item.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}).text if dr_item.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}) else None
    dr_scraper['specialties'] = dr_item.find('li', {'class':'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'}).text if dr_item.find('li', {'class':'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'}) else None
    dr_scraper['review_count'] = dr_item.find('div', {'class':'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'}).text if dr_item.find('div', {'class':'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'}) else None
    dr_scraper['language_english'] = dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-English'}).text if dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-English'}) else None
    dr_scraper['language_spanish'] = dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}).text if dr_item.find('li', {'data-test':'language-Spanish'}) else None
    dr_scraper['overall_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-0'}).text if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-0'}) else None
    dr_scraper['wait_time_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-1'}).text if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-1'}) else None
    dr_scraper['bedside_manner_rating'] = dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-2'}).text if dr_item.find('div', {'data-test':'reviews-section-header-rating-2'}) else None
    dr_data.append(dr_scraper)
```

A more maintainable solution would be:

```
PROPS = [
    ('name', 'span', 'itemprop', 'name'),
    ('specialties', 'li', 'class', 'krbmlv-5 cpBnTD'),
    ('review_count', 'div', 'class', 'sc-1evbz6z-2 qKvtL'),
    ('language_english', 'li', 'data-test', 'language-English'),
    ('language_spanish', 'li', 'data-test', 'language-Spanish'),
    ('overall_rating', 'div', 'data-test', 'reviews-section-header-rating-0'),
    ('wait_time_rating', 'div', 'data-test', 'reviews-section-header-rating-1'),
    ('bedside_manner_rating', 'div', 'data-test', 'reviews-section-header-rating-2')
]

for dr_item in soup_dr:
    dr_scraper = {}
    for attr_name, tag, prop_name, prop_value in PROPS:
        element = dr_item.find(tag, {prop_name: prop_value})
        if element:
            dr_scraper[attr_name] = element.text
        else:
            dr_scraper[attr_name] = None
    dr_data.append(dr_scraper)
```